# File-based key-value store that is concurrency-safe and NFS-safe

Tags: python, cross-platform, key-value-store

I am looking for a Python 3.7+ library for a key-value store that:

- Can take tuples of primitive types as keys & values
- Stores its data on disk so that it persists between processes
- Does not require a server process
- Is thread-safe and multiprocessing-safe
- Works on NFS
- Works on Linux, macOS, and Windows
- Can handle a collection of data up to about 1 GB in size
- **BONUS:** Can clear out old entries to reduce the on-disk storage to a given size

The best I've found so far is [diskcache](https://pypi.org/project/diskcache/), but that uses SQLite databases, which are not reliable on NFS.

Comment: I doubt you can find anything like this. As shown in the [SQLite FAQ](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5), SQLite claims that NFS implementations have a lot of problems with the file locking needs by concurrent writes, so I don't think any other program or library could make them reliable. Your best bet would be to use a server based database.

Comment: @Alejandro: Things like [flufl.lock](https://flufllock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) provide NFS-safe locking, so something built on that could work.  And a server is 100% out of the question for my needs.